# Freemarker inserts redundant punctuation in href attribute

Tags: html, freemarker

I have a Freemarker HTML template which includes:

```
<#assign addr>${serverAddress}activate/${user.id?string.computer}</#assign>
<p> 
<a href="${addr}">${addr}</a>
</p>
```

The output HTML that results from this markup (assuming that ${serverAddress} = "http://myserver.com/", and ${user.id} = 20) is:

```
<a href="\"http://myserver.com/activate/20\"">http://myserver.com/activate/20</a>
```

The additional \" at the beginning and end of the href attribute don't cause a problem, but they are unnecessary and inelegant. I don't understand why they are there, and I don't know how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the answer. It is simply to omit the quotes around the value of the href attribute: so instead of

```
<a href="${addr}">${addr}</a>
```

I write

```
<a href=${addr}>${addr}</a>
```

and the output is as expected.

Not at all intuitive, but hey it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write this:

```
<#assign addr = “${serverAddress}activate/${user.id?string.computer}” >
```

It’s according to Freemarker best practice: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_assign.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can write it that way, but it makes no difference at all to the generated output.